# How to render a modal based on what is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I have a modal that renders a form. I have an add button, when I click this button the form opens. However, I would also like to reuse that form to be able to edit the items created using the form when I click the div of a particular item.

So how can I tell my app when to render the add items part and when to render the edit items part? I use context for the modal, it only has the default value (false). The modal opens when I click both the button and the item, but the add form is default.

Here is what my form looks like:

```
const AddEditForm = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useContext(DataContext)
  const [modal, setModal] = useContext(DataContext2)
  const { item, setItem, id, updatedItem, setUpdatedItem } =
    useContext(DataContext3)
  const [editForm, setEditForm] = useState(false)
  const STATUS = ['-', 'todo', 'inProgress', 'done']
  const USERS = ['-', 'Unassigned', 'JD', 'AJ', 'SS']

  const toggleOnClick = () => {
    addItem()
    setModal(!modal)
  }

  const toggleOnClickEdit = () => {
    UpdateItem()
    setModal(!modal)
  }

  const addItem = () => {
    if (item.status === 'todo' && item) {
      setList((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          todo: {
            title: 'Todo',
            tasks: [
              ...prev.todo.tasks,
              {
                id: v4(),
                title: item.title,
                status: item.status,
                user: item.user,
                description: item.description,
              },
            ],
          },
        }
      })
    } else if (item.status === 'inProgress') {
      setList((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          inProgress: {
            title: 'In Progress',
            tasks: [
              ...prev.inProgress.tasks,
              {
                id: v4(),
                title: item.title,
                status: item.status,
                user: item.user,
                description: item.description,
              },
            ],
          },
        }
      })
    } else {
      setList((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          done: {
            title: 'Done',
            tasks: [
              ...prev.done.tasks,
              {
                id: v4(),
                title: item.title,
                status: item.status,
                user: item.user,
                description: item.description,
              },
            ],
          },
        }
      })
    }
    setItem({ title: '', description: '', status: '', user: '', id: v4() })
  }

  const UpdateItem = () => {
    console.log('this is the edit form')
  }

  return (
    <form>
      {editForm ? (
        <div>
          <h2> Edit Task</h2>
          <label htmlFor="title">Title: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={item.title}
            required
            placeholder={item.title}
            onChange={(ev) => setItem({ ...item, title: ev.target.value })}
          />
          <label htmlFor="description">Description: </label>
          <input
            type="textarea"
            id="description"
            value={item.description || ''}
            name="description"
            placeholder={item.description}
            onChange={(ev) =>
              setItem({ ...item, description: ev.target.value })
            }
          />
          <label htmlFor="status">Status: </label>
          <select
            className="form-select"
            id="status"
            required
            value={item.status}
            placeholder={item.status}
            onChange={(ev) => setItem({ ...item, status: ev.target.value })}
          >
            {STATUS.map((status) => (
              <option key={status} value={status}>
                {status}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <label htmlFor="user">User: </label>
          <select
            className="form-select"
            id="user"
            required
            value={item.user}
            placeholder={item.user}
            onChange={(ev) => setItem({ ...item, user: ev.target.value })}
          >
            {USERS.map((user) => (
              <option key={user} value={user}>
                {user}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <button type="button" onClick={toggleOnClickEdit}>
            Update
          </button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h2> Add Task</h2>
          <label htmlFor="title">Title: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={item.title || ''}
            required
            onChange={(ev) => setItem({ ...item, title: ev.target.value })}
          />
          <label htmlFor="description">Description: </label>
          <input
            type="textarea"
            id="description"
            value={item.description || ''}
            name="description"
            placeholder="Describe your task..."
            onChange={(ev) =>
              setItem({ ...item, description: ev.target.value })
            }
          />
          <label htmlFor="status">Status: </label>
          <select
            className="form-select"
            id="status"
            required
            value={item.status || ''}
            onChange={(ev) => setItem({ ...item, status: ev.target.value })}
          >
            {STATUS.map((status) => (
              <option key={status} value={status}>
                {status}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <label htmlFor="user">User: </label>
          <select
            className="form-select"
            id="user"
            required
            value={item.user || ''}
            onChange={(ev) => setItem({ ...item, user: ev.target.value })}
          >
            {USERS.map((user) => (
              <option key={user} value={user}>
                {user}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <button type="button" onClick={toggleOnClick}>
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </form>
  )
}

export default AddEditForm
```

Thanks, hopefully this will help someone out too!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add click on your modal in html and pass current data through that modal.
2. In your clicked function, set your form data to passed data from the parameters

   clicked(data){
   this.editForm =  this.fb.group({
   title: item.title,
   status: item.status,
   user: item.user,
   description: item.description
   })
   }